# Error returned in Web Service

Tags: php, netbanx-api, paysafe

I have been having a hell of a time trying to debug this. I am running out of ideas. I have the following simple PHP code.

```
$url = "https://webservices.test.optimalpayments.com/creditcardWS/CreditCardServlet/v1";          
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"&txnMode=".$txnMode."&txnRequest=".urlencode($ch));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Unfortunately every time I try to run this I keep getting an problem with XML request. Here is the request.

```
$txnRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<ccAuthRequestV1 xmlns=\"http://www.optimalpayments.com/creditcard/xmlschema/v1\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.optimalpayments.com/creditcard/xmlschema/v1\">\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<merchantAccount>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<accountNum>".$account."</accountNum>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<storeID>".$merchantId."</storeID>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<storePwd>".$merchantPwd."</storePwd>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "</merchantAccount>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<merchantRefNum>".$merchantRefNum."</merchantRefNum>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<amount>".$amount."</amount>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<card>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<cardNum>".$cardNum."</cardNum>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<cardExpiry>\n<month>".$eMonth."</month>\n<year>".$eYear."</year>\n</cardExpiry>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<cardType>".$cardType."</cardType>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<cvdIndicator>".$cvdIndicator."</cvdIndicator>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<cvd>".$cvd."</cvd>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "</card>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<billingDetails>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<cardPayMethod>WEB</cardPayMethod>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<firstName>".$firstName."</firstName>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<lastName>".$lastName."</lastName>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<street>".$bStreet."</street>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<city>".$bCity."</city>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<state>".$bState."</state>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<country>".$bCountry."</country>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<zip>".$bZip."</zip>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<phone>".$bPhone."</phone>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "<email>".$bEmail."</email>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "</billingDetails>\n";
                $txnRequest .= "</ccAuthRequestV1>";
```

Can anyone provide some insight as to what is not encoded properly?

Comment: Echo out your `$txnRequest` and examine the final data. I'm guessing you may need to encode your XML before you post it like that.

Comment: `.urlencode($ch)` Whats happening there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@aynber is correct, it looks like you are not encoding the correct part of your request.

I believe the correct way of doing this would be like this.

```
    $url = "https://webservices.test.optimalpayments.com/creditcardWS/CreditCardServlet/v1";           
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"&txnMode=".$txnMode."&txnRequest=".urlencode($txnRequest));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Hope that this helps.

Answer (score -2):

I think @Steve is on the right track. Perhaps you meant urlencode($txnRequest))

Also, validate your xml before sending it out.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer